# Segues won't work after adding new navigation controller and root controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboard

I just inherited a project that uses a Storyboard + nibs.

The Storyboard had a navigation controller set as the initial view controller, and then had the first view controller set as its root. Very simple.

I decided to create a new view controller and make that the new root controller. I still have the old root view controller, its just not the root anymore. So for speed, I deleted the navigation controller, selected my new root view controller, and embedded it inside of a navigation controller.

Worked perfectly. Here's what I don't understand...

My setup looks identical to what was there before, but I had to add the following to the app delegate:

```
  LaunchController *launch = [[LaunchController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LaunchController" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:launch];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  [self.window setRootViewController:navigation];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Why did I have to add this, but the previous version didn't need it, even though I feel like the changes I made still kept the setup identical to what I had before?

Throughout the app, `performSegueWithIdentifier` is being called and now those always fail and say "Receiver has no segue with identifier."

If I remove the above code from the app delegate, then my root controller that's both a nib and on the Storyboard doesn't show on screen. It loads, but you can't see anything. However, now all of my segues work.

So what's going on here? I realize I probably screwed something up when creating a new navigation controller and root view controller, but I can't figure this out.

I have been spending some more time working with nibs, and I've been adding the above app delegate code, so I really don't even understand how the previous developer was making this work in the first place without that code in the app delegate.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboard then you don't have to write any code in App Delegate class. Instead you mention your storyboard like Project file -> Targets -> General -> Deployment Info -> Main Interface.
[image: Screenshot for XCode setting] Here you see Main_iPhone is my storyboard for the project. Now any View Controller inside that storyboard which is set as "Is Initial View controller" will be loaded by the app automatically for you.